# Trying to make a switch in a iqueryable any

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

I have five columns Cc1, Cc2, Cc3...
And I have the following switch statement in the "Any" to check in the columns based on the ccLevel, but the test1 table has 32 million rows and it takes forever to get them, is there a better way to make it faster?

```
if (_db.Test1.Any(x => CCLevels(x, ccLevel) == cCValue.CcCode))
        {
           some Message...
        }

if (_db.Test2.Any(x => CCLevels(x, ccLevel) == cCValue.CcCode))
        {
           some Message...
        }


private string CCLevels<T>(T x, string ccLevel) where T : IccLevels
    {
        string level = null;
        switch (ccLevel)
        {
            case "1":
                level = x.Cc1;
                break;
            case "2":
                level = x.Cc2;
                break;
            case "3":
                level = x.Cc3;
                break;
            case "4":
                level = x.Cc4;
                break;
            case "5":
                level = x.Cc5;
                break;
        }
        return level;
    }
```

When I make it like the following it takes a second,

```
if (_db.Test1.Any(x => x.Cc1 == cCValue.CcCode))
        {
            some Message...
        }

if (_db.Test1.Any(x => x.Cc2 == cCValue.CcCode))
        {
            some Message...
        }
```

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more? What language is this? C#?

Comment: c# Linq-to-Entities